# Add image inline after specific text

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to append an image (the logo of the website) after the words "Camera e Colazione" are in a Paragraph.

I tried with CSS adding manually a span class but I'd like to do it automatically with Javascript.

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless this is for learning purposes, I highly recommend just using CSS for this.

Comment: Maybe I was not so precise but I'd like to do it automatically. I meant it will be in Wordpress and as soon as the editor will use the words "Camera e Colazione" it will render an image inline afterwards. Hope is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox, see example bellow:

```
<div class='container'>
     <p> Camera e Colazione </p>
     <img src='...'/>
</div>
```

// CSS

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: 'row'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way, you can use **jquery** code as below:

```
var sp =$("p").text().split("Camera e Colazione");
$("p").text("");
$("p").append(sp[0]);
$("p").append("Camera e Colazione");
$("p").append($('<img id="sampleImg">'));
$("p").append(sp[1]);
```

This is not the best way. But it works.

Comment: Is it possible to do it only with Javascript?

Comment: yes. sure.for get text of paragraph you can use getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML.  for append element, you can use appendChild(). for split you can use split(" "). for replace you can use replace(" "  ,  " ").